# Can multiple VM's use a single NIC in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I am new to azure cloud ,some can help me to understand the VM--NIC assignment, the Multiple VM's can use single NIC in azure ??

Comment: Are you sure this is not the otherway around? I don't know a way to have multiple VM's use the same NIC

Answer (score 2):

In the new Resource Group model, you can create a NIC as an atomic, region based, entity. You can then assign and unassign that Nic to a VM at will. So if you want to retain the MAC address of a specific Nic across a number of VMs that is possible. However you can only use a Nic in one VM at a time.

Comment: @RajeshSwarnkar what does that even mean? - every answer to a question should be a direct answer, are you saying all answers should be written in all bold! (that's not even getting into why say this on a seven year old answer!)

Comment: Could you please clear the edit queue. It says its full.

Answer (score 1):

No

refer the constraints while creating NIC in Azure

Constraints
A VM must have at least one network interface attached to it.

A VM can only have as many network interfaces attached to it as the VM size supports. To learn more about how many network interfaces each VM size supports, see Sizes for virtual machines in Azure. All sizes support at least two network interfaces.

**The network interfaces you add to a VM can't currently be attached to another VM.**

Answer (score 0):

The answer is YES!
Definitely, multiple VMs can use a single Network Interface Card---- BUT ONLY ONE VM AT A TIME.
Azure allows you to create a NIC as a separate entity. So, at one time, it can be attached to only one VM. But you can, at any time as per your business requirement, detach and assign it to any other VM.